# How to use An Array of Values on Multiple Values of Multiples Inputs in HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, object, httprequest

This page had created for save multiple people at the same time. People object have three properties `fullname`, `birthday`, `country`. All properties have added as one value of a single input, separating them by `","` like an array. This would be easy if i use `Jquery` `ajax` methods. But i wonder how to do this only using `html`. Is this a bad practice?

I got a trouble using properties which includes `","`. Im thinking adding more properties later. Such as "address", "description" which can contains any of character including ",". What is the most efficient method?

```
<form method="POST" action="save.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="person[]" value="Jhon Doe,1990-04-05,USA" >
    <input type="hidden" name="person[]" value="Roe Smith,1998-11-21,UK" >
    <input type="hidden" name="person[]" value="Ama Sarala,1996-06-06,Sri Lanka" >
    <input type="hidden" name="person[]" value="Sophie Jones,1993-02-07,USA" >
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Server side code:

```
foreach ($_POST["person"] as $value) {
    $exp = explode(",", $value);
    echo "Full Name:".$exp[0];
    echo "Birth Day:".$exp[1];
    echo "Country:".$exp[2];
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Are you having an issue? Where I have had problems is trying to do multiple arrays, say `person[]`, `birthday[]`, `city[]`... or something like this - and then not having them match up when one isn't filled in. But what you are doing seems fine at first glance to me.

Comment: "I got a trouble" What exactly is the trouble you're having? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? If not, what is the result you are getting, and what is the result that you are expecting? What debugging have you already done?

Comment: I thinking add their "address" as a property. If i got a value from a user input which includes ",", i have to let them insert ",". So  Is there an universal separator for support any user input.

Comment: why not use different inputs for different properties ?